# How to use SDK of SmartEyeglass in "Xamarin"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I would like to use Xamarin software as developing "Smart eye glass" which is Sony products.

I am wonderring that "sony_smarteyeglass_sdk_v1.5"  is allowed to use in "Xamarin"?

I know that "AndroidStudio" is compatible with Sony products(Smartglass).

Comment: You could create `Xamarin.Android` binding libraries for the `SmartExtensionAPI` / `SmartExtensionUtils` / `SmartEyeglassAPI` jars. Or send me a pair of those and I'll do it for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The SmartEyeglass SDK is really just a set of java libraries for Android that give you the correct interface to the SmartEyeglass device. All of the code runs on the Android device and therefore you have access to any functionality that any other Android app has.